# Is the function $ \exp(2\pi i /\epsilon) $ equivalent to zero?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Is the function

$$ f\left(\frac{x}{\epsilon}\right)=\exp\left(\frac{2\pi ix}{\epsilon}\right)=g(x) $$

equivalent to zero ? in the limit $ \epsilon \to 0 $ ?

If I take the derivative $$\frac{ g(x+\epsilon)-g(x)}{\epsilon} $$ is $0$ because the function $g(x)$ has a period 'epsilon'

Also if I take the integral of $g(x)$ is $0$ almost everywhere

So is this function equivalent to $0$ ??

Comment: Are you asking about the function itself or the pointwise limit?  Perhaps you could make the question clearer.

Comment: For any $\epsilon\ne0$, the function $f(x/\epsilon)$ is not equivalent to zero. The limit of $f(x/\epsilon)$ as $\epsilon\to0$ does not exist, so there is no sense in asking whether the limit is equivalent to zero.

Comment: I suspect that if you actually mean to take a limit of *tempered distributions* rather than a limit of *functions* that the result might be zero. But the question you posted is definitely false, and the reasoning wrong.

Comment: I.e. in terms of ordinary functions, if $h(x)$ is *sufficiently nice* (e.g. being a schwartz function is probably good), I believe it is true that $$ \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  h(x) \exp(2 \pi i x / \epsilon) \, \mathrm{d}x = 0$$Pay attention to the fact this is taking a limit of the values of the integral, ***not*** the limit of $\exp(2 \pi i x / \epsilon)$.

Comment: am ok :/( i misunderstood that

Comment: In fact, @Hurkyl's statement would follow immediately from the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma

Answer (score 2):

You cannot take the derivative with the same $\epsilon$ as that in the function.

$$\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\frac{e^{2i\pi\epsilon/\epsilon}-1}\epsilon\ne
\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\lim_{\eta\to0}\frac{e^{2i\pi \eta/\epsilon}-1}\eta.$$

Answer (score 1):

$|g(x)|=1$ for all real numbers $x$ and all $\epsilon >0$. How can $g$ be equivalent to $0$?